# Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure

Tags: jenkins

I have a build step in my jenkins project. This is an Execute Shell step.

The following is the command is what I am running.

```
sudo gcloud --project=xxxx preview app deploy app.yaml ==version=1
```

During the deployment the above step breaks the build, with the following error.

sudo gcloud --project=cfc-melbourne-website preview app deploy app.yaml ==version=1

> ```
> We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
> Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:
>
>     #1) Respect the privacy of others.
>     #2) Think before you type.
>     #3) With great power comes great responsibility.
>
> sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
> Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
> No JDK named ‘null’ found
> ERROR: Build step failed with exception
> com.google.jenkins.plugins.credentials.oauth.GoogleRobotPrivateKeyCredentials$AccountIdNotSetException
>   at com.google.jenkins.plugins.credentials.oauth.GoogleRobotPrivateKeyCredentials.getUsername(GoogleRobotPrivateKeyCredentials.java:152)
>   at com.google.jenkins.plugins.credentials.oauth.RemotableGoogleCredentials.<init>(RemotableGoogleCredentials.java:54)
>   at com.google.jenkins.plugins.credentials.oauth.GoogleRobotCredentials.forRemote(GoogleRobotCredentials.java:204)
>   at com.google.jenkins.plugins.storage.AbstractUpload.initiateUploadsAtWorkspace(AbstractUpload.java:342)
>   at com.google.jenkins.plugins.storage.AbstractUpload.perform(AbstractUpload.java:173)
>   at com.google.jenkins.plugins.storage.GoogleCloudStorageUploader.perform(GoogleCloudStorageUploader.java:109)
>   at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
>   at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:785)
>   at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:726)
>   at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:185)
>   at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:671)
>   at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1766)
>   at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
>   at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
>   at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
> Build step 'Google Cloud Storage Uploader' marked build as failure
> Finished: FAILURE
> ```

How do I resolve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `no tty present` error indicates that you have the requiretty setting in your sudoers file. This will require a tty. To solve this you can add your user to that file and turn .

change your sudoers-file:

```
vi /etc/sudoers
```

and add (assuming it's your jenkins-user):

```
Defaults:jenkins !authenticate
```

Normally your jenkins user can use sudo-commands without authentication.