# Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure after timeout

Tags: jenkins

I have this commands:

```
php artisan config:clear
timeout 15 php artisan queue:work
php artisan queue:restart
```

The jobs fails with:

```
+ php artisan config:clear
Configuration cache cleared!
+ timeout 5 php artisan queue:work
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I need to stop that command `php artisan queue:work` after 15 seconds, that's why I'm ussing `timeout`.

Why I'm having this error? without the timeout everything works ok.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33802424/build-step-execute-shell-marked-build-as-failure

Comment: @Rob why is duplicate? In that question, the error is present `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified` in my case I just have a timeout that I put then it exits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this: https://www.howtoforge.com/linux-timeout-command/#q-how-to-get-commands-exit-status-in-output

`timeout`'s exit code when it succeeds is 124.

Since the exit code of the script isn't 0 (either because that's the last command you run, or because you `set -e` in your script), Jenkins takes that as a failure.

Since you know that the non 0 exit code isn't a failure, you can work around this by piping your command to another command that always exits with exit code 0, eg:

`timeout 5 php artisan queue:work | :`